# java.lang.runtimeexception unable to start activity componentinfo error

Tags: android

I need to integrate Google + in my Android application, I am following this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/ but when i run my project, this message appears in the emulator **Unfortunately your App has stopped** and this is the error in the logcat :

```
java.lang.runtimeexception unable to start activity componentinfo com.example.testgoogle/com.example.testgoogle.MainActivity:java.Lang.NullPointer.Exception:Null options are permitted for this API.
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.I need your help please.Thank you in advance.

Here are My logs:

```
04-15 07:42:38.906: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1315): Google Play services is missing.

04-15 07:42:38.936: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1315): Google Play services is missing.

04-15 07:42:39.666: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1315): Internal error occurred. Please see logs for detailed information

04-15 07:42:39.846: I/Choreographer(1315): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

04-15 07:42:40.256: I/Choreographer(1315): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

04-15 07:42:44.716: E/SettingsRedirect(1315): Can't redirect to app settings for Google Play services
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.runtimeexception unable to start activity componentinfo error when integrating Google + in my Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29229447/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo-error-when-int)

Comment: "Google Play services is missing" is a fairly obvious problem.  Start by figuring out if your device has the Google Play Store app?  If not, you won't be able to use this.  If you are using an emulator, make sure you are using a Google APIs image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your api client by using

```
// Initializing google plus api client
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

use `addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())`
instead of `addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)`

Do not use null,use **Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build()**

this will solve your issue for sure

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help , but i still have a problem; when i run my project, an other message appears "Unknown issue with Google Play Services" and when i press "Ok" , an other message appears " This app won't run without Google Play Services, Which are missing from your phone"  but when i press the button  "Get google play services" so  my click on "Sign in with Google +"   , the message " Unfortunately your App has stopped" appears again and the app is stopped .  Please, i need your help . Thanks in advance